# How to install cross-compiled OpenCV's libraries on Raspberry Pi

Tags: cross-compilation, opencv

My problem is may be complicated, I'll try to detail

I cross compiled `opencv` for ARM (Raspberry Pi) from my host, and everything works fine.
I also tried to cross compile an example and it also worked; I got an executable.

But once the executable transferred to the raspberry, I cannot execute it and I get the following error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.3.0: can not
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory.

On my host, in my opencv's build folder, I have an `install` folder in which there are four subfolders: `bin`, `share`, `include`, `lib`. What am I suposed to do with these folders?  I think I must use their content but don't know how.

Where and how do I install the cross compiled libraries in raspberry? How could I fix that error?

Answer (score 2):

- You need to change CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in the cmake build command which points to /usr/local to RPi_rootfs/usr/local where RPi_rootfs is the root file system path which is present in your SD Card. After Cross-Compilation when you press

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

  all the SO files will be placed in your Raspberry Pi's root filesystem. You can then boot your RPi and check the opencv installation.
- You can also make CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX to a local folder and do

  ```
  rsync -avz local_opencv_install_folder destination_root_filesystem/usr/local
  ```

  where local_opencv_install_folder is the path of the folder specified in CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and destination_root_filesystem is the root file system of raspberry pi present in sd card. Check for appropriate permissions to write to  root file system of raspberry pi's /usr/local folder, sudo might be needed here. This method is particularly helpful when making OpenCV installations in multiple SD Cards.

This problem can be solved in a different way like, How to build opencv in a host computer:
[How to install OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 3 in Raspbian Jessie?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69169/how-to-install-opencv-on-raspberry-pi-3-in-raspbian-jessie/70626#70626)

In the above link Chrooting into raspberry Pi filesystem using qemu is done, once chroot is obtained all dependencies of opencv along with building and installing of opencv is done.

Comment: Please do include relevant parts of the information in the link here on this site.

Comment: @Bex added some details, is it okay now?